# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter.I dont understand why i have error.I convert my response from json to object.Why this method `getUser` return null?

```
 Future<UserResponse> getUser(String apiToken, int id) async {
        try {
          Response response = await _dio.get(apiEndpoint + "users/",
            queryParameters: {
              "id": id,
            },
            options: Options(
                headers: {
                  "Authorization": apiToken
                }),
          );
       return UserResponse.fromJson(response.data);//'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
          
        } catch (error, stacktrace) {
        
        }
    
  }

 UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    surname = json['apiToken'];
    response = json['response'];
  }
```

Comment: check `response.data` maybe the response is list, if so use `response.data[0]` to get the first one if that's what you need, or if you want to get all map through them `response.data.map((user) => UserResponse.fromJson(user)).toList();` and change the return type to  Future<List<UserResponse>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your `/users` endpoint returns a list of user objects, but `UserResponse.fromJson` expects his input to be a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

You could try the following:

```
 return response.data
      .map<UserResponse>((el) => UserResponse.fromJson(el))
      .toList();
```

But it seems like you are only expecting one user as you provide the `id` of the user in your query parameters. Are you sure that the user id should be a query parameter?

Your code resolves to this:

```
/users/?id=<id>
```

couldn't it be

```
/users/<id>
```

In this case you need to change to this:

```
Response response = await _dio.get(apiEndpoint + "users/$id",
    options: Options(
        headers: {
           "Authorization": apiToken
        }),
    );
```